# How to get pony to set proper envelope sender?

Tags: ruby, pony

I'm using Ruby with Pony to send email. I can't seem to get the envelope sender to be changed to what I want; something in Pony or the code underneath it always substitutes the **user_name** parameter.

Any suggestions for this? I can get a text name like "Network Ops" in front of the email address by using the **header** parameter, but the actual email address is still incorrect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind -- it is the Gmail SMTP daemon rewriting the sender envelope. I tested against another (Qmail) server and this didn't happen.

Pony is great!